# Understanding $1$-forms as 'onions'

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, intuition, differential-forms

I stumbled across [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1099&rep=rep1&type=pdf) providing an intuition of differential forms. On page $3$ the paper reads

*"Think of a vector as a pin and a one-form as an onion. You evaluate a one-form on a vector by counting how many onion layers it goes through. More generally we represent a one-form on an $n$-manifold by drawing $(n − 1)$-dimensional surfaces on it. We call these surfaces **leaves**. In the general case we can still count how many of these leaves each vector goes through. [...] This picture makes it easy to integrate a one-form."*

[image]

I understand the definition of a $k$-form, as well as [this](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/preprints/forms.pdf) (different?) interpretation of them, yet the phrase *"You evaluate a one-form on a vector by counting how many onion layers it goes through"* remains a mystery to me.

**What does the quoted passage mean?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your differential form is $dx$, and you evaluate it on the vector $c \ \partial_x$, you get $c$, because it "pierces through $c$ depth of the onion $dx$". $dx$ evalutes to $0$ on other directions, so if I add some component $a \ \partial_y,$ the vector gets longer but I don't pierce more onion of $dx$, I just stuck the toothpick in on an angle.

Comment: I see now. Do you happen to understand the following phrase _"$df$ is represented as the contour lines of $f$ with the contours corresponding to equally spaced ’heights’"_?

Comment: Yes. Think about what this means in a coordinate. Then $d$ (in two dimensions) acts on $f$ by $df = \partial_x f \ dx + \partial_y f \ dy$. This is nothing more than $\nabla f \cdot (dx, dy)$, so at any given point, you have something which looks roughly like the picture in the OP, but parallel to the gradient of $f$. You get the contour lines because this $1-$form is actually the derivative of something, so they can be integrated, i.e. "smoothed out" into a continuous contour line.

Comment: I understand that $df=\nabla f \cdot (dx,dy)$, but how does that imply that "at any given point you have somthing which looks roughly like the picture in the OP, but parallel to the gradient of $f$".