# Interpreting exterior products as intersection of diagrams

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, intuition, differential-forms

[This paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1099&rep=rep1&type=pdf) provides an intuition of $k$-forms. On page $4$ it reads:

*"In order to represent the exterior product of two $n$-forms you find the intersection of the diagrams representing the forms. For example if we draw $dx$ as vertical lines and $dy$ as horizontal lines then $dx ∧ dy$ is the set of intersection points which will form a uniform grid."*

[image]

[image]

**Why can the exterior product of two forms be interepreted as the intersection of the diagrams representing the forms?**

---

This is a follow-up to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4677120/understanding-1-forms-as-onions).

Comment: Earlier in the paper the author says 'Visualising a ∧ b is easy: it’s the little parallelogram that has the vectors a and b as its sides', and now he claims it is the intersection!

Comment: @JMP - The wedge product of _vectors_ is the parallelogram, but the wedge product of _covectors_ is the intersection.