# Why can $df$ be represented as the contour lines of $f$ with the contours corresponding to equally spaced 'heights'?

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition, differential-forms

I stumbled across [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1099&rep=rep1&type=pdf) providing an intuition of differential forms. On page $4$ the paper reads

*"$df$ is represented as the contour lines of $f$ with the contours corresponding to equally spaced 'heights'"*

**Why is this the case?**

---

An explanation in the comments of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4677124/362026) goes as follows:

*"Think about what this means in a coordinate. Then $d$ (in two dimensions) acts on $f$ by $df=∂xf dx+∂yf dy$. This is nothing more than $∇f⋅(dx,dy)$, so at any given point, you have something which looks roughly like the picture in the OP, but parallel to the gradient of $f$. You get the contour lines because this $1$−form is actually the derivative of something, so they can be integrated, i.e. "smoothed out" into a continuous contour line."*

to what I answered in the comments:

*"I understand that $df=∇f⋅(dx,dy)$, but how does that imply that 'at any given point you have somthing which looks roughly like the picture in the OP, but parallel to the gradient of f'?"*

Comment: Check out Missner Wheeler Thorne and Needham's Visual Differential Geometry

Answer (score 1):

The way to think about is, to increase "x" we have to move across horizontal lines. Similarly to increase "f", we have to move along contour lines. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4677120/688539), you see that contour lines of the function $g(x,y)=x$ is just horizontal lines the $x-y$ plane . Similarly to increase $f$, we need to cut across contour lines of $f$.

If we are at a point in the domain, then the contour lines which we cut of $f$ is propotional to the projection of our "step" along the direction perpendicular to our contour.

Shortly put, $df(v) = \nabla_v f$

Comment: To get something straight: are the contour lines _parallel_ or _pendendicular_ to $\nabla f$?

Comment: Perpendicular @Sam